# Java code increment values by 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way of incrementing a value of a variable by the power of 10 in a loop. For example:

```
int x = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  // 1st time x = 1, 2nd time x = 10, 3rd time x = 100, 4th time x = 1000
}
```

I want to avoid using the pow function because that appears to have higher performance than some simpler multiplication method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just maintain a variable and multiply it on each iteration?

```
int x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    x *= 10;
    // do something with x
}
```

However, I'd recommend using `Math.pow` if you don't need the intermediate values. It'll be just as fast as that if not faster for some cases.

Comment: Unfortunatly Math.pow only provides a method for doubles. Which isn't bad when you have doubles, but causes unneeded overhead when using any integer type.

Answer (score 6):

You can do plain iteration.

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100000; i *= 10) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrgmSrs20 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100000; i=i*10) {
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
    }
}
```